# Python pyodbc insert in for loop

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm trying to get urls and using extruct json and rdfa data by using libraries. Somehow there is a mistake in code and getting an sql error.

The code is below

```
import pyodbc
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import extruct

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL 
Server};SERVER=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=WebCrawler; 
Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select Id, url from WebCrawlerEFs")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
print (row.Id,",", row.url)
r = requests.get(row.url)
data = extruct.extract(r.text, r.url)    
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RdfaEFs(rdfa) VALUES ('"data"')")     
cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: File "sql.py", line 13
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RdfaEFs(rdfa) VALUES ('"data"')")
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try:cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RdfaEFs(rdfa) VALUES ('?')", (data, ))

Comment: Please format your code and edit the error message you have (in the comments) into the question itself. Use the edit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RdfaEFs(rdfa) VALUES (?)", (data, ))
```

Comment: File "sql.py", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RdfaEFs(rdfa) VALUES ('?')", (data, ))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: ( cc: @BerkayYerdelen ) You have the right idea, but it should be `VALUES (?)` not `VALUES ('?')`

Comment: @GordThompson: Thanks.